# Native IIS module event ordering

Tags: c++, iis, iis-modules

I'm working on a native IIS module (c++) which needs to capture request and response buffers inorder to reconstruct a complete transaction.

Below is my `RegisterModule` call:

```cpp
HRESULT __stdcall RegisterModule(
    DWORD dwServerVersion,
    IHttpModuleRegistrationInfo* pModuleInfo,
    IHttpServer* pGlobalInfo
) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwServerVersion);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pGlobalInfo);
    return pModuleInfo->SetRequestNotifications(new AgentModuleFactory, 
        RQ_BEGIN_REQUEST | // OnBeginRequest
        RQ_READ_ENTITY   | // OnReadEntity
        RQ_SEND_RESPONSE | // OnSendResponse
        RQ_END_REQUEST     // OnEndRequest
        ,
        RQ_END_REQUEST // Specify post-event notifications
        );
}
```

The basic idea of my module is in

- `OnBeginRequest` - start recording a transaction (capture any metadata associated with a request)
- `OnReadEntity` - capture the request buffer
- `OnSendResponse` - capture the response buffer
- `OnEndRequest` - close off the transaction and perform any needed operations against it

Nothing I'm doing needs to change any data passing through the server, I just need to take a copy of it.

Now logically, the events I'm hooking should flow in the order that I've listed them above however  for some reason, `OnEndRequest` is firing followed by `OnSendResponse` which makes no sense.

Going by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/smooth-streaming-client/chttpmodule-class#nondeterministic-request-events , `OnSendResponse` is concidered a nondeterministic request event and can fire in any order but having it fire after a request has "ended" is a bit weird.

Has anyone got any experience with this/is this normal behavious? Is there a better way to detect that a request has trully ended?
Alternatively, am I looking at this completely wrong and the IIS request processing pipeline ends with a call to `OnEndRequest` (at which point a response has been generated but not transmitted) followed only by the a call to `OnSendResponse` to close things out.

Thanks for any light anyone can shed on this problem.

Comment: Clearly you answered with your “alternatively” part.

Comment: In the IIS module, especially when processing request events, the triggering sequence of events is usually controlled by the IIS kernel. In theory, your expectation is correct: OnBeginRequest should be called first, then OnReadEntity, then OnSendResponse, and finally OnEndRequest. In practice, some changes may occur.